# Desktop doesn't show up as an option when I try to change directories

Tags: directory

I am trying to change my Ubuntu directory into "Desktop". I have tried running "cd ~/Desktop" however it responds with "-bash: cd: /home/mcosentino/Desktop: No such file or directory".
When I am in my home directory and I run "dir" the only 3 directories it shows are "lammps  lammps-stable_3Mar2020  stable_3Mar2020.tar.gz".
Why can't I connect to my Desktop and/or Documents when I use cd?

Comment: Are you actually running a desktop (GUI) version of Ubuntu? or is it a server (CLI only) version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS- not sure which version this is.

Comment: Hello. a few things. you can edit your posted question with your answers above. First of all, you aren't root are you? If not, as a regular user type cd and press return, then pwd. what does it say? Then cd ~ press return, and pwd again. what does that say? And also echo $HOME , what does that say? these should be redundant, but just checking. Also if you can tell or post the output of cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs. AND to make steeldriver's question a little more clear to you. Do you (normally) have an actual visual "desktop" you are working on, or do you have the black console screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are Italian the Desktop is called "Scrivania". Anyway if you open your terminal you have to type:

```
$ ls -al
```

The command **ls** means "list"

**-a** means show the hidden files and directories

**-l** it show also the permissions

In this way you can see all the file and directories in your home directory. The "dir" command come from Dos.

Comment: When I run that line it returns a larger list: ., .., .bash_history, .bash_logout, .bashrc, .landscape, motd_shown, .profile, .sudo_as_admin_successful, .wget-hsts, lammps, lammps-stable_3Mar2020, stable_3Mar2020.tar.gz. But Desktop is still not an option? (my computer is not italian)

Comment: If you dont have file or directory like Desktop, Public, .Xdefaults, .Xresources, .Xauthority, means that your ubuntu is installed without Xorg (withhout the windows manager). Then you have access to your system only by shell or cli (character user interface). Also I see the file ".landscape" that means your installation is a server. Usually the servers are installed without Graphical User Interface (aka Xorg or windows manager). Then you haven't your Desktop folder because you haven't a desktop.